# when call api using ajax jQuery validation annotation not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on an ASP.NET Core MVC application I call API using ajax jQuery to prevent change URL after click submit button.

From

```
Resignation/RequesterIndex?filenumber=103085
```

to

```
Resignation/RequesterIndex
```

and call ajax jQuery working success without change URL but on same time validation annotation model state not working.

How to display validation?

```
public class ResignationRequester
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dept./ Branch: ")]
    public string Dept { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Designation: ")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action method:

```
public class ResignationController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult RequesterIndex(string filenumber)
        {
            return View(resignationRequester);
        }
       
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequesterIndex(ResignationRequester resignationRequester)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Workforce.InsertToReignation(resignationRequester, (string)Session[SessionKeys.Username], (DateTime)Session[SessionKeys.LastWorkingDate], noticeperiod, (int)Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ViewBag.errorMsg = "Create Not Done Correctly";
                    }

                    Session[SessionKeys.DirectManager] = GetEmployeeName(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.DirectManager));
                    Session[SessionKeys.LineManager] = GetEmployeeName(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager));

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMsg))
                    {
                        ViewBag.successMessage = "Resignation Submission form Created successfully";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                                            .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                                            .ToList();
                    ViewBag.errorMsg = "Some Required Fields Not Added";
                    goto InvalidModel;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMsg = "No Data For This File No";
            }

            InvalidModel:

            ViewBag.isPostBack = true;

            return View(resignationRequester);
        }
}
```

View `ResignationRequester.cshtml`

```
@model HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.ResignationRequester

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Requester Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("RequesterIndex", "Resignation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "ResignationApp", style = "padding-top: 50px" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMsg))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @ViewBag.errorMsg
        </div>
    }

    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.successMessage))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            @ViewBag.successMessage
        </div>
    }

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dept, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dept, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dept, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Designation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Designation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Call jQuery ajax will call action Requester Index on Resignation Controller

```
$("#ResignationApp").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                console.log("data is" + formData)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "Resignation")',
                   data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#successMessage").show();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                });
            });
```

I do investigation about that and found issue on ajax jQuery call

```
e.preventDefault();
```

when remove it validation working but on same time URL will change

How to make validation work and URL not changed?

**Expected result**

When leave department or designation empty then it must display validation required for me

Required validation error without change URL

but this is not happening....

If I remove `e.preventdefault` from jQuery it will solve issue validation, but at the same time URL will change from:

```
Resignation/RequesterIndex?filenumber=103085
```

to

```
Resignation/RequesterIndex
```

**Updated Post**

```
if ($("#validateFrom").valid()) {
```

what jquery scripts needed for running valid()
or you meaning validate()

Comment: You're trying to do two different things at the same time.  The validation output that you see is in response to posting a form.  But you're not posting a form, you're sending an AJAX request.  If you want to use AJAX then these validation tools won't work, you'd have to use something else (even just manual input validation in the client-side code).  Which do you want to do?  Post the form (thus loading a new page) or make an AJAX request (thus staying on the same page)?

Comment: You can just add: onsubmit="myAjaxCall(formID); return false;" to your <form> tag.  (instead of adding eventhandler in jQuery...)  You can then check in your method for valid... ex: valid = $('#' + formID).valid();
 
    if (valid) {  ...do your thing... }

Comment: can you check updated post

Comment: .valid comes from jquery.validate... it should be included in your layout, but dynamically rendered pages may need it... ex: <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>  In your layout it's in "Shared" folder as "_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ajax jQuery working success without change URL but on same time
> validation annotation model state not working .
>
> so How to display validation ?

Well, first of all what [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) has explained is correct, because [model state validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-state) taken place in server side your ajax or client side doesn't know about that unless you are using razor.

Another point is that, you are mixing both client side which is jQuery and [ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-state) together which shouldn't work this way.

> When remove it validation working but on same time URL will change
>
> so How to make validation working and URL not changed ?

No, you don't need to change or remove `e.preventdefault`. What you can do is, set a `form id` and and write one additional function and use from validation attribute in jQuery by using `$("#YourFormId").valid()` in order to keep all existing code as it is and its easy and less change required.

Let's have a look in practice how we can achieve that:

Demo Model:

```
public class TestValidationModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RequesterIndex(TestValidationModel user)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

```
    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model MVCWebApp.Controllers.TestValidationModel
<form id="validateFrom">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" id="txtName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
    {
  

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                if ($("#validateFrom").valid()) {
                    $('#validateFrom').submit();
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#validateFrom").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                console.log("data is" + formData)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "ModelStateValidation")',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#successMessage").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** As you can see, by using `$("#validateFrom").valid()` it would check the form value and based on correct input it will proceed to form submit.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you check updated post

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, You can include this CDN link `"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"` which I have already put in the answer. Let me know if you need any more assistance on this.